# External dependencies in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

How to pass project related dependencies(External dependencies)which are not available in central,Remote Maven repositories in Azure Pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new maven feed in Azure Artifacts and publish the dependencies that are not available in the remote central Maven repository in the newly created maven feed.
You can install Maven artifacts from your feed by using the Maven client.The most common way to install a Maven artifact is as a dependency of another artifact.

For details,please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-maven?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts